# Google Assistant Session Entity Some time working sometime not working.. nodejs

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

i have one code.. that given from action on google .. sometime its working sometime its not.. help me if anyone have any idea..
session entity is not working properly

```js
const dialogflowAPI = require('dialogflow');
const sessionClient = new dialogflowAPI.SessionEntityTypesClient();
const client = new dialogflowAPI.EntityTypesClient();
const entityList = ['measure','dimension','size'];
const size = ['top','bottom','high','highest','low','lowest'];
exports.entityList=entityList;
exports.size=size;
exports.createSessionEntityType = async function(conv,entityName,entityValues){
try{
    const sessionEntityType = {
    name: conv.body.session + '/entityTypes/'+entityName,
    entityOverrideMode: 1,
    entities: entityValues,
  };
  const request = {
        parent: conv.body.session,
        sessionEntityType: sessionEntityType,
  };
  console.log(sessionEntityType);
  const [response] = await sessionClient.createSessionEntityType(request);
} catch(e) { 
   console.log(e); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to handle session entities is different for Actions on Google. Instead of calling an API, you provide the entities in your webhook response. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-session) shows the new way to provide this information. It also gives a code snippet for how you can do it in the Node.js library.

```
app.intent('input.welcome', (conv) => {
  conv.ask('make your choice: apple or orange?');
  // Set the fruit session entity values to 'apple' and 'orange'.
  const responseBody = conv.serialize();
  responseBody['sessionEntityTypes'] =  [ {
    name: conv.body.session + '/entityTypes/fruit',
    entities: [{
        value: 'APPLE_KEY',
        synonyms: [
          'apple', 'green apple', 'crabapple'
        ]
     },
     {
        value: 'ORANGE_KEY',
        synonyms: [
         'orange'
        ]
     }],
    entityOverrideMode: 'ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_OVERRIDE'
  }];
  conv.json(responseBody);
});
```

Comment: only single entity is working... if i have 2 entity called "measure" and "dimension".. that time last entity ("dimension") is working.. if i have single entity called "measure" that time that "measure" is working properly.. so basically only single entity working.. i want multiple session entity... Thanks

Comment: ``Nodejs


const responseBody = conv.serialize();
   responseBody['sessionEntityTypes'] =  [ {
    name: conv.body.session + '/entityTypes/'+entityName,
    entities: entityValues,
    entityOverrideMode: 'ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT',
    Kind:'KIND_MAP'
   }];
   conv.json(responseBody);
``

Comment: i have 3 different entity.. at a time only one entity is working which is last pushed..

Comment: But are you setting all the session entities in the right level of the array?

Comment: done bro thanks..single entity only working in single intent.. i make 3 new intent for 3 entity.. and it worked :)